# supress warnings thrown by server in server.log

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am using Wildfly 8 for my deployment. Our application uses JDBC to access database. The database resource management from Java code is not proper, like when a connection is closed, many of its associated statements or resultsets are not closed. So when I am closing a connection, the following WARN is thrown by the server:

```
21:52:35,702 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection] (EJB default - 1) Closing a statement you left open, please do your own housekeeping: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.registerStatement(WrappedConnection.java:1677)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.<init>(WrappedStatement.java:105)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.<init>(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:69)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6.<init>(WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6.java:52)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6.wrapPreparedStatement(WrappedConnectionJDK6.java:79)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:405)
```

How to suppress such warning messages such that they do not appear in server.log of Wildfly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default configuration, then `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` is an XML file which contains the logging configuration for your server. The XPATH `/jboss:server/jboss:profile/logging:subsystem` will take you to an element which contains a number of `logger` elements, each with a `category` and a `level`. The category is the name of the logger being configured, for example `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection` and the level name is the threshold being set on that logger. If you set the logging level to `ERROR`, like the following configuration, then any WARN logs will be suppressed.

```
<logger category="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection">
    <level name="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```

It's still better to actually resolve the erroneous code, but this will do what you've asked.

Answer (score 2):

You should fix your code, not just suppress the log that is telling you that you have written bad code